# RabbitMQ config Queues Listener in YAML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

First of all I'm sorry for my English. I'm doing a high school job, and I need to set up the RabbitMQ queue name in a YAML file for my listener, and I could not. I made the application using application.properties in spring-boot, and it worked, but I need to change to YAML. can you help me?

My application.yaml

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    port: 5672
    host: 'localhost'
    username: root
    password: root
  queue:
    name: queue-test
```

Thank you =)

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @Deadpool 
I do not receive the message in my listener. I do the post normally to the queue, but in my onMessage method, I do not get the messages. No error appears on the console.

Comment: when switched to application.properties, works normally. But my teacher asked YAML.

Comment: can you show your `application.properties` and how are you reading those properties in your code?

Comment: my application.properties is: 

server.port=8002

spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=root
spring.rabbitmq.password=root

queue.name=queue-pubsub-test

and my application.yaml is:
camunda.bpm:
  admin-user:
    id: demo
    password: demo
    firstName: Demo
    lastName: Demo
  filter:
    create: All Tasks
server.port: 8080
spring.devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true

spring:
  rabbitmq:
    port: 5672
    host: 'localhost'
    username: root
    password: root
  queue:
    name: queue-pubsub-test

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below yaml sample structure:

```js
# RabbitMQ properties
  rabbitmq:
   addresses: localhost:5672
   adminAddresses: http://localhost:15672
   nodes: rabbit@localhost
   username: guest
   password: guest
   virtual_host: /
   useSSL: false
   sslProperties:
   ssl:
     keyStore:
     keyStorePassphrase:
     trustStore:
     trustStorePassphrase:
   channelCacheSize: 100
```

Comment: Hi Ompratap. 
but how does he identify the name of my queue he needs to listen to? Because my producer is in another microservice, running local on my machine. Just stopped working my listener when I change to YAML, if it is properties, it works normally. I'm a beginner in programming, sorry for my bad programming skills.

Comment: For define queue name either you can add under rabbitMQ or create new heirchaly like: application->queeu-listner1->name and same need to configure in your code also.